# 2 - Calabi Yau algebras and bimodule coherence

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, noncommutative-geometry, calabi-yau

Let $\Pi:=\Pi(Q)$ be the preprojective algebra of a connected non-Dynkin quiver over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero.
In H. Minamoto "Ampleness of two-sided tilting complexes", Int. Math. Res.
Not. (2012), 67-101, it is proved that $\Pi$ is graded left and right coherent.

Anybody knows if $\Pi$ is also bimodule coherent i.e. if the kernel of any morphism between finite rank free $\Pi-$bimodules is finitely generated?

In general: does anybody know any example of a $2-CY$ algebra, in the sense of Ginzburg - Bocklandt, which is bimodule coherent?

Thanks

Francesco

Comment: Cross-posted on MSE: [http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/661926/...](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/661926/2-calabi-yau-algebras-and-bimodule-coherence)

Comment: Hi It is the first time I post a question: would it be better I don't cross-post? Thanks

Comment: It seems to be considered better practice not to cross-post (see [this meta thread](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/423/close-cross-posts-between-here-and-mse), for instance).

Comment: Thanks @Pierre-Guy Plamondon. I think that mathoverflow is the more appropriate site. I'll remove the question from math.stackexchange.